# Azure storage custom domain name still retain azure domain?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Probably a very silly question, however I cannot see an explicit quotation about the following:

1. I currently have the default Azure storage domain, say: http://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/
2. I want to map a custom CNAME for example: myazurestore.mydomain.com to the above storage account.

I currently have an application which has code to refer to the endpoint in item 1 above, which I don't want to upset.

With a new part of the system, I can hopefully use the mapped subdomain in item 2, however I don't want to break the existing app pointing to the default azure domain.

So again, very silly question, but guessing the mapping of a custom domain still leaves the default azure domain active?? (i.e. similar to websites and so on?)

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding custom domains will not break the Azure-assigned domain.  You're safe!

Comment: Thank you!  it's what I thought, given the way the other services on Azure work, however it doesn't harm to ask and check!  So, many thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a custom domain for accessing blob data in your Azure storage account. The default endpoint for the Blob service is https://.blob.core.windows.net. If you map a custom domain and subdomain such as www.contoso.com to the blob endpoint for your storage account, then your users can also access blob data in your storage account using that domain.

[Azure Docs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/)

Comment: that does not say you can't use both

Comment: Yes, thanks for the summary, and I did get the idea I could map a custom domain, but as @RobertLevy mentioned, it was more about if I could use both and it wouldn't break existing retrievals.. I know it might be an obvious point, but I have an app with quite a bit of reliance on the existing azure domain url and so didn't want to risk it if I had missed something obvious!

Many thanks though, appreciated.